# customerRepositoryInterface->save does not update attribute "is_active"

Tags: magento2, customer-account

I'm trying to update "is_active" attribute but nothing happens in the database. I don't get an error message either. What am I doing wrong?

```
public function changeStatus($statusData)
{
    $customer= $this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById($statusData['id']);
    $customer->setData('is_active', 0);
    }
    try{
        $this->customerRepositoryInterface->save($customer);
    } catch (\Exception $e ){
        throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());  
    }
}
```

Comment: Does anyone have an idea ?